# Simple Motor driver circuit diagram help

Tags: mosfet, schematics, dc-motor

I am trying to create a small motor driver for a DC motor, 9 V - 12 V. Max current and stall current I do not know, but I am using the stock motor of a Blade CP Helicopter. I just want to know if I am using parts that will work and what parts I should replace. 
The FET i am using is a 22N50 N-channel FET. Any advice or things I should look out for?

Motor will be only going one direction and will be controlled from a 3 V - 5 V PWM

Yes, I know about the diode across the motor which is a 1N4000.

The schematic:
[image]

Comment: Do you have the motor part number?

Comment: its a 370 Motor, i looked for more info but not too much on it

Comment: well the design works, but i dont know the limitations or what could fail. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGv7ZcKn0Z0  tested with 5v through the motor, 5 volts on gate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on the 'net' gives the following

Model: R370

Round type diameter: 24.4 x 30.8 (L)

Voltage (V): 6.0
No load current 0.03 A; speed 4,950 rpm
Max efficiency current 0.19 A; speed 4,280 rpm; torque 19 gcm
Max output current 0.625 A; speed 2,475 rpm; torque 170 gcm
Stall current 1.22 A; torque 140 gcm

Voltage (V): 31.0
No load current 0.035 A; speed 11,140 rpm
Max efficiency current 0.2 A; speed 9,530 rpm; torque 43 gcm
Max output current 0.63 A; speed 5,570 rpm; torque 149 gcm
Stall current 1.22 A; torque 298 gcm

- This sounds like a possible for your motor...

If the motor you have is about this size (24.4mm Dia x 30.8mm L), then its stall current will be about the same.

And for your FET - a max current around 22A peak around 80A

This FET should easy handle the stall current for your motor.

Comment: I think that answers my question about the schematic, thanks!  I am going to have to email the manufacture for the exacts, about the motor, but it looks pretty close to the r370.

Comment: 370 is a standard size of 'toy' motor - it appeared in radio controlled cars in about the late 1970's - there were a couple of motors that were used - the big one was the 540 can size. - the main difference between the motors was how the coils inside were wound. For racing cars a thicker wire would be used that would take a lot more current, but the downside was the batteries would run down quicker... (And everything would have to take a lot higher current)

Comment: As you motor is from a model helicopter, the motor is a more standard design - and won't have specs much off the ones quoted for the R370 - I would say a max stall current of no more than 5 Amps...

Comment: You could test the stall current by just connecting the motor across a supply with a meter and stall it - but only for less than 2 seconds...

Comment: Your design for a motor controller is simple, it seems to work and should be capable of handling the stall current from your motor. :-)